# Run all testthat tests for an R package?

Tags: r, testthat

I googled, found [this](https://rdrr.io/cran/testthat/man/test_dir.html); accordingly, ran `test_dir()` (it errors), tried `test_dir(getwd())` from the package root (it also errors). I also tried `test_package()`, but it also errors if the argument is left `NULL` or returns nothing if the package name is provided as a string.

#### Question

How do you quickly run all tests in a package from the R console (assuming `getwd()` is at the package root)?

#### Note

I know you can `R CMD check` but I don't need the other checks, just the tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply run

```
devtools::test()
```

Note there are also some other methods [here](https://testthat.r-lib.org/reference/test_package.html)